# MultiTrigger.Condition are not working in MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

i have the next XAML in MAUI

```xml
<Button.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger TargetType="Button">
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Email, Converter={StaticResource IsStringNotNullOrWhiteSpaceConverter}}"
                              Value="True" />
            <BindingCondition  Binding="{Binding IsValid, Source={x:Reference EmailValidator}}"
                               Value="True" />
            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Password, Converter={StaticResource IsStringNotNullOrWhiteSpaceConverter}}"
                              Value="True" />
            <BindingCondition  Binding="{Binding IsValid, Source={x:Reference PasswordValidator}}"
                               Value="True" />
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="IsVisible"
                Value="True" />
    </MultiTrigger>
</Button.Triggers>
```

and when i launch the program, the status is

Current Status:

[image]

I mean, the MultiTrigger should have the property IsVisible in False, but is True.
What's happening here?

Only in this case, the Button should be Visible

[image]

Comment: Maybe the problem is the windows render, becouse if i move or resize the windows, the button change the IsVisible value.

Comment: Have you tested on other platforms?

Comment: Yes, sorry, this problem only happen in Windows. I´m tested in Android simulator and Android Device (Tablet and Mobile) and working fine. I just update Visual Studio 2022 and i think that the problem have been fixed in latest version